# MatInput datetime-local input control doesn't render properly on latest version of Chrome

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is how the control is rendered:

[image]

Here is the markup behind:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>End date</mat-label>
  <input [formControl]="endDateControl" name="endDate" matInput type="datetime-local">
</mat-form-field>
```

Chrome version:

> Version 122.0.6261.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)